# xError When compiling Dcmi

Tags: c, stm32, hal, coocox

Excuse my English.

I want to set up DCMI in HAL, because use CooCox have to copy the code from the generator cubeMX

The compiler does not like the line:

```
__HAL_LINKDMA(hdcmi, DMA_Handle, hdma_dcmi);
```

Code:

```
void DCMI_DMA_init(void){
        GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
        __GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
        __GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
        __GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
        __GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
        __DCMI_CLK_ENABLE();
        __DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

        HAL_NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(NVIC_PRIORITYGROUP_2);
        HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DCMI_IRQn, 0, 0);
        HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DCMI_IRQn);

        /*
        PE4      ------> DCMI_D4
        PE5      ------> DCMI_D6
        PE6      ------> DCMI_D7
        PA6      ------> DCMI_PIXCK
        PC6      ------> DCMI_D0
        PC7      ------> DCMI_D1
        PC8      ------> DCMI_D2
        PC9      ------> DCMI_D3
        PD3      ------> DCMI_D5
        */
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5 | GPIO_PIN_6;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF13_DCMI;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF13_DCMI;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6 | GPIO_PIN_7 | GPIO_PIN_8 | GPIO_PIN_9;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF13_DCMI;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF13_DCMI;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

        hdcmi.Instance = DCMI;
        hdcmi.Init.SynchroMode = DCMI_SYNCHRO_HARDWARE;
        hdcmi.Init.PCKPolarity = DCMI_PCKPOLARITY_FALLING;
        hdcmi.Init.VSPolarity = DCMI_VSPOLARITY_HIGH;
        hdcmi.Init.HSPolarity = DCMI_HSPOLARITY_HIGH;
        hdcmi.Init.CaptureRate = DCMI_CR_ALL_FRAME;
        hdcmi.Init.ExtendedDataMode = DCMI_EXTEND_DATA_8B;
        hdcmi.Init.JPEGMode = DCMI_JPEG_DISABLE;
        HAL_DCMI_Init(&hdcmi);

        hdma_dcmi.Instance = DMA2_Stream1;
        hdma_dcmi.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_1;
        hdma_dcmi.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
        hdma_dcmi.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_ENABLE;
        hdma_dcmi.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
        hdma_dcmi.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_WORD;
        hdma_dcmi.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_WORD;
        hdma_dcmi.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
        hdma_dcmi.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_VERY_HIGH;
        hdma_dcmi.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_ENABLE;
        hdma_dcmi.Init.FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFO_THRESHOLD_FULL;
        hdma_dcmi.Init.MemBurst = DMA_MBURST_SINGLE;
        hdma_dcmi.Init.PeriphBurst = DMA_PBURST_SINGLE;
        HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_dcmi);

        // Macro code:
        //hdcmi->DMA_Handle = &hdma_dcmi;
        //hdma_dcmi.Parent = hdcmi;
        __HAL_LINKDMA(hdcmi, DMA_Handle, hdma_dcmi);
}
```

Error:

```
   [cc] C:\.......\libs\ov7670\OV7670_control.c: In function 'DCMI_DMA_init':
   [cc] C:\.......\STM32F429xx_cmsisboot\source\Hal/stm32f4xx_hal_def.h:95:43: error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'DCMI_HandleTypeDef')
   [cc] (__HANDLE__)->__PPP_DMA_FIELD__ = &(__DMA_HANDLE__); \
   [cc] ^
   [cc] C:\.......\libs\ov7670\OV7670_control.c:249:2: note: in expansion of macro '__HAL_LINKDMA'
   [cc]   __HAL_LINKDMA(hdcmi, DMA_Handle, hdma_dcmi);
   [cc]   ^
   [cc] C:\.......\STM32F429xx_cmsisboot\source\Hal/stm32f4xx_hal_def.h:96:55: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'void *' from type 'DCMI_HandleTypeDef'
   [cc] (__DMA_HANDLE__).Parent = (__HANDLE__); \
   [cc] ^
   [cc] C:\.......\libs\ov7670\OV7670_control.c:249:2: note: in expansion of macro '__HAL_LINKDMA'
   [cc]   __HAL_LINKDMA(hdcmi, DMA_Handle, hdma_dcmi);
   [cc]   ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *__HAL_LINKDMA(**&**hdcmi, DMA_Handle, hdma_dcmi);* instead seems to solve.